# Maven Dependency Nightmare

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I am very new to programming and am working my way through a tutorial for Hibernate that includes using Maven. Everything seemed to be going well until I try to mvn compile or spin up my HSQLDB server using the recommended command in the tutorial:

mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.hsqldb.Server" -Dexec.args="-database.0 file:target/data/tutorial"

At that point I get a build failure which I will include below, along with my pom. It seems to be telling me that poms are missing for the dependencies but I have no idea how to correct that problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated so that I can move forward with my learning experience. 
[image]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.hibernate.tutorials</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-tutorial</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-snapshot</version>
<name>First Hibernate Tutorial</name>

<build>
     <!-- we dont want the version to be part of the generated war file name -->
     <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Because this is a web app, we also have a dependency on the servlet api. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate uses slf4j for logging, for our purposes here use the simple backend -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate gives you a choice of bytecode providers between cglib and javassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Be aware of that the `<finalName>...</finalName>` only handles the name in your local directory `target` but does not influence the name which is deployed into local repo via `mvn install` or in remote repository `mvn deploy`....If you are working in IDE like Eclipse it does not matter...

Comment: What is the alternative?

Comment: There is no alternative, cause you don't need to change the name...If you run in exec-maven-plugin you can use the defaults etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [search.maven.com](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hibernate%7Chibernate-core%7C5.0.7.Final%7Cjar), it appears that the Hibernate dependency name is `hibernate-core-5.0.7.Final`. That is, a capital `F` in `Final`. So try with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

instead

Comment: I did not actually fix with this specific action but I think you are correct so I have marked right. What a small but important detail, and I believe you are correct. I ended up finding a site this morning with a post about many flaws in this tutorial that make it very difficult to complete. I suppose that is how we learn.